# Add days to date - counting deadline

Tags: vba, date, formula

Can someone help me with this problem.

I need a macro or a formula that adds 8 days to the date in cell A1 and display it in cell A2. If the 8th day is weekend or holiday then in it needs to display next first workday. I also need macro to display first workday after that in cell A3.

Holidays are in cells G1 to G20.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [Networkdays](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-function-00cbaf0a-7112-4a31-95b6-3724396daf9c) built in function. You might not VBA to do this. Now, if you need VBA, please show us your attempts and your issues or errors encountered.

Comment: I tried with Workdays formula but failed. Haven't tried in VBA because I don't know how to code.

Comment: this link seems related to your issue https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227592%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell A2, place the formula

```
= WORKDAY( A1+7, 1, G1:G20 )
```

This simply adds seven straight days to whatever is in cell A1 and then adds 1 **working day** to that. So that's your first workday which is >= the 8th day after whatever date is in A1.

In A3 then simply write

```
= WORKDAY( A2, 1, G1:G20 )
```

which adds another working day to whatever date is in A2.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly. I also have tried that version of workday formula, but I couldn't get it to work properly. Thanks again.